# how to set anothe path - cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I would like to start `cmd.exe` from batch file and execute command, but: 
If I use  `start cmd.exe /k`  e.g. `„net use“` – it executes command behind /k.  - and it gives me default path - i would like to change it.

But how to run `cmd.exe` with another path as it is set and execute command behind `/k`? 
I start cmd.exe    - i have  - `c:\users\xxxx`
What do i have to if i would like to chande it?   E.g. `c:\tools\Script\...`

How to write batch like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

> cd "pathname"

to get to the correct Path.
For Example:

> cd c:\tools\Script

you can also show all folders by using the command

> dir

Furthermore the cmd.exe is automatically used if you try to execute a .bat file I believe.
But for changing the normal path used you can edit the settings as shown in this picture:
[image]

For more funcitons you could look here: http://www.computerhope.com/overview.htm

Answer (score 2):

Use the `start /d` parameter, e.g.

```
start "" /d"c:\documents and settings" cmd /k
```

see `start /?` for more help.